# Smoothing groups, Hard / Soft edges very confusing

Tags: modeling

**Asked this on rightclickselect but they said i should post it here :**

Hi,

Its Christmas, so merry Christmas. With it being Christmas it gives me a bit of time to play about in blender which is nice. however i am still very confused by the mark hard soft edge / Auto smoothing in Blender. in Maya its straight forward and clear as day but in blender i find it very confusing since coming from a Max and Maya background. i watched a video where a guy set the auto smoothing to 180 degrees and them marked hard and soft edges which seemed in his video to work. i tried this with strange results. either i'm doing something super wrong or the system is a bit bazaar. then there is shade smooth and shade flat...which is again another method.

so that is 3 methods?

**Auto smooth, hard/soft edge** and **shade smooth/Flat**???

is this going to get simplified / improved with 3 methods to do the same thing is seem utterly confusing to have so many methods all of which from what i see don't really play well with each other and from what I've seen there isn't one that overrides the other. the hard and soft edges seem like the logical winner, if you set it manually that is what it should be IMO.

Perhaps someone with more Blender knowledge and experience can enlighten me to where i am going wrong. Ultimately id prefer the Maya hard and soft edge to be the way to be doing this in blender and with the auto smoothing being a default that can be manually overridden.

Thanks P

Comment: Those aren't different methods. They are options related to each other and allowing next one from the chain to work. Smooth shading is in the root, the rest of options have no sense without it. Then AutoSmooth which defines general angle and accepts manual defining certain edges (in Blender this is Mark Sharp). It isn't clear what isn't clear for you regarding to video you watched, I think you should edit the question with video link and explain what didn't work for you

Comment: Hi Zak, thanks for trying to help. The main problem i have been having is with having a smooth curve top and flat sides. think i have figured it out now thanks to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfDBVjLyQtc

but i don't think its fast or a great way of doing it tbh. from this the best way to do it it not use the hard and soft edges at all and go via the smooth shade and smooth flat method. which is old school imho.  anyway i'll battle on with this.

Comment: i still don't get it. here is an example .

if i turn auto smooth off. i get a curve tring to smooth itself vertically even though both sides are set to flat shaded and the polys are set to smooth. the half capsule shades fine here ( they are both the same model) 

![**Image1**](https://imgur.com/a/8MtE3IB)

once i set auto smooth on the curve looks as expected. but the half capsule shades wrongly no matter what i set. 

![**Image2**](https://imgur.com/a/oilBTFC)

pretty lost. not experienced this in any other program. can anyone show me how i solve this or what i am doing wrong